# setup project vs2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

every time i do build to setup project on vs2010 its starts sql manager 2008 process for a while and build. the process takes couple of minutes.

in 2008 it did not do that 
any thoughts why ?
G

Comment: You should probably give a bit more details regarding to the nature and composition of the the original project and the setup project.

Comment: Is it an ASP.NET project or any other kind of project that uses a membership/role provider?

Comment: Well guys, i dont know why the sql manager pops every time i build a msi project but i simply press cancel and its stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an "answer."  But I have some information.  This (or a very similar) question was asked in [how do I stop sql server 2008...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040970/how-do-i-stop-sql-server-2008-r2-trying-to-install-some-package-when-i-build-my-s).  In my case, I had installed VS 2010 (Ultimate) from a Passport drive; SQL 2008 was installed from an ISO image.  If I simply plug in the passport drive (VS2010 source) when building the Setup project, the issue "goes away" in the sense that it does not show the dialog.  My hunch is that it is still doing the same work, but is finding what it wants (quickly) on the passport drive.  If I disconnect the external drive, the problem returns.  So if the message is correct and VS 2010 is trying to configure something, it never really gets configured; but it gets past it quickly if it can find its install source.

Someone who has spent more time working with all the configuration pieces might be able to do more with this information.